# Scala traits stacking

Tags: scala

I have the following traits:

```
trait A
trait B extends A
trait C extends B
```

I have to now stack these traits:

```
trait Stackable extends C
```

Is B and A automatically stacked in Stackable? or should I explicitly stack them using with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `Stackable` will extend/mixin `C`, `B`, and `A`

It's not necessarily wrong to explicitly mention them, i.e. `trait stackable extends C with A`; this won't cause any problems, but it's unnecessary. Ultimately it's up to you and your judgement to decide whether it makes sense to call them out explicitly.